Rounding the edges of the PyQT6 window Web interface, web widget web Python
I need to round the Pyqt6 window with a web interface, a web widget, so that the edges are even, QSS does not work in this case, because the interface is not QT, setMask works, but it is impossible to make even corners with it. I need to come up with something, I haven't been able to do it for a week.
I have attached the code.
class FramelessWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.resize(850, 590)
        self.setMinimumSize(850, 590)
        self.setMaximumSize(850, 590)
mainWindow = FramelessWidget()
mainWindow.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
mainWindow.resize(850, 590)
mainWindow.setMinimumSize(850, 590)
mainWindow.setMaximumSize(850, 590)
mainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(web)
mainWindow.show()
print(mainWindow.hasMouseTracking())
application.exec()

We tried to install a central widget and it doesn't work through QSS, there is already a similar question, but I don't understand how to solve it with my code.
Antialiasing( add smoothness) when masking a window for round-corner in PyQt5
